# Stylus interpolation doesn't work for media query value

Tags: stylus

I am trying to use variables in a media query in stylus using interpolation but I've noticed that you can only seem to use variables in the property name and not the value. The following code works:

```
lgScreen = "992px"

@media (min-{lgScreen}: 992px)
    .something
        background red
```

But this code doesn't

```
lgScreen = "992px"

@media (min-width: {lgScreen})
    .something
        background red
```

I get the following error:

```
ParseError: expected ":", got "}"
```

How can I generate my media query using my variable for the min-width value?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to interpolate in that position. Remove the braces and [it should work fine](http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=lgScreen%20%3D%20992px%0A%0A%40media%20(min-width%3A%20lgScreen)%0A%20%20%20%20.something%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20background%20red).

You'll probably also want to remove the quotes in the variable declaration because they'll get output in the media query, too.